# I Don't want to rollback some things into DB Transaction

Tags: database, laravel

What i want is insert record into system logs when error occurs and other things are rollback.

**Below line is main thing into code :**

> \Log::error('Error occurs : unable to find record');

I have following code :

```
public function read()
    {
        $id = 'some-id';
        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();

        $record = $this->getRecordsFromTableA($id);

        // some mor actions are here
        //
        //

        DB::commit();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollBack();
    }
}

private function getRecordsFromTableA($id)
{
    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();

        $company = TableA::find($id);
        if (!$company) {
            throw new ApiOperationFailedException();
        }

        DB::commit();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollBack();

        // i don't want to rollback this change and this will add record into system_logs
        \Log::error('Error occurs : unable to find record');

        throw new ApiOperationFailedException($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove commit and rollback function from read function like this.

```
public function read()
    {
DB::beginTransaction();
        $id = 'some-id';
        try {
        $record = $this->getRecordsFromTableA($id);
 DB::commit();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
 DB::rollBack();
 // i don't want to rollback this change and this will add record into system_logs
        \Log::error('Error occurs : unable to find record');

        throw new ApiOperationFailedException($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont do that because both functions are used from multiple places @Narayan Sharma

Comment: @VishalRibdiya you can't do this without removing from the main function as per your current implementation. What you can do is just place exception handler from child function to parents function exception handler. 
Please check the updated code above.

Comment: Thanks @Narayan Sharma for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You are not inserting into the database. You only query the database. DB::rollback() rolls back records inserted into the database after DB:: beginTransaction(). Since no records where inserted, there isn't any records to rollback. Thanks and goodluck